# Sqlalchemy get records with less than N parents

Tags: sqlalchemy

How to get records with less than 3 parents or without parents?

Hello everyone! I have 3 tables: Product, Order and User. Product and Order, Product and User are linked many to many.
How to get products with less than 3 orders and users?

My query is:

```
stmt = select(User).where(Product.user_id == User.id).subquery()
stmt1 = select(Order).where(Order.user_id == User.id).subquery()

select(Product)
.outerjoin(Product.orders)
.outerjoin(Product.users)
filter(
       and_(
          select(func.count("*")).select_from(stmt).as_scalar() < 3,
          select(func.count("*")).select_from(stmt1).as_scalar() <3,
       )
)
```

If I remove the second condition from _and, I get 36 products, although I only have 20.
If I apply scalars().unique().all(), I get 20 products, although I should get less, because some of them already have 3 users or 3 orders.
With second _and condition I get 0 products

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have many-to-many relationships, I'll assume you must have at least association tables (if not association objects).

I have managed to extend from your query, using the association tables and it returns the expected results.

```py
stmt = (
    select(Product)
    .outerjoin(Product.orders)
    .outerjoin(Product.users)
    .group_by(Product.id)
    .having(
        and_(
            select(func.count())
            .select_from(product_order_AT)
            .where(product_order_AT.c.product_id == Product.id)
            .as_scalar()
            < 3,
            select(func.count())
            .select_from(product_user_AT)
            .where(product_user_AT.c.product_id == Product.id)
            .as_scalar()
            < 3,
        )
    )
)
```

Now, it's not very pretty but it is readable, and produces the output you seem to want.

---

Full demo.

```py
from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    Integer,
    Table,
    and_,
    create_engine,
    func,
    select,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


product_order_AT = Table(
    "product_order_AT",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("order_id", ForeignKey("order.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("product_id", ForeignKey("product.id"), primary_key=True),
)

product_user_AT = Table(
    "product_user_AT",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("user_id", ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
    Column("product_id", ForeignKey("product.id"), primary_key=True),
)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    orders = relationship(
        "Order", secondary=product_order_AT, back_populates="products"
    )
    users = relationship(
        "User", secondary=product_user_AT, back_populates="products"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Product(orders={self.orders}, users={self.users})"


class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = "order"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = relationship(
        "Product", secondary=product_order_AT, back_populates="orders"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Order(id={self.id})"


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    products = relationship(
        "Product", secondary=product_user_AT, back_populates="users"
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User(id={self.id})"


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True, future=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    p1 = Product()
    p2 = Product()
    p3 = Product()
    p4 = Product()

    o1 = Order()
    o2 = Order()
    o3 = Order()
    o4 = Order()

    u1 = User()
    u2 = User()
    u3 = User()
    u4 = User()

    p1.orders.extend([o1, o2, o3, o4])
    p1.users.extend([u1, u2, u3, u4])

    p2.orders.extend([o1, o2, o3, o4])
    p2.users.extend([u1, u2])

    p3.orders.extend([o1, o2])
    p3.users.extend([u1, u2, u3, u4])

    p4.orders.extend([o1, o2])
    p4.users.extend([u1, u2])

    session.add_all([p1, p2, p3, p4])
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    stmt = (
        select(Product)
        .outerjoin(Product.orders)
        .outerjoin(Product.users)
        .group_by(Product.id)
        .having(
            and_(
                select(func.count())
                .select_from(product_order_AT)
                .where(product_order_AT.c.product_id == Product.id)
                .as_scalar()
                < 3,
                select(func.count())
                .select_from(product_user_AT)
                .where(product_user_AT.c.product_id == Product.id)
                .as_scalar()
                < 3,
            )
        )
    )
    print(session.scalars(stmt).all())
```

prints

```py
[Product(orders=[Order(id=2), Order(id=1)], users=[User(id=1), User(id=2)])]
```